# Convolutional Neural Network training returns illogical values

Tags: c#, networking, convolution, convnetsharp

I am using https://github.com/cbovar/ConvNetSharp to use convolutional neural networks in my application.

Unfortunately the libary is not well documented at all.
But anyway I have a question about the training process:

I declared a dictionary of types string and List of Bitmaps.

I then added some letters ( exempli gratia a, b, c et cetera) with its corresponding names to the dictionary.

After this, I create the neural network as follows:

```
            Network.AddLayer(new InputLayer(Width, Height, 1));

        Network.AddLayer(new ConvLayer(5, 5, NumberFilters) { Stride = 1, Pad = 2 });
        Network.AddLayer(new ReluLayer());

        Network.AddLayer(new PoolLayer(2, 2) { Stride = 2 });

        Network.AddLayer(new ConvLayer(5, 5, NumberFilters * 2) { Stride = 1, Pad = 2 });
        Network.AddLayer(new ReluLayer());

        Network.AddLayer(new PoolLayer(3, 3) { Stride = 3 });

        Network.AddLayer(new FullyConnLayer(TrainingSet.Count));
        Network.AddLayer(new SoftmaxLayer(TrainingSet.Count));
```

If I now start the training process by this method:

```
        public void StartTraining()
    {
        _initializeLayers();
        _locked = true;
        int _increment = 0;

        Console.WriteLine("Training...");

        foreach (var data in TrainingSet)
        {     
            for (int i = 0; i < data.Value.Count; i++)
            {
                var map = MapBmpToDouble(data.Value[i]);
                var input = new Volume(map, new Shape(map.Length));
                var output = Network.Forward(input, true);
                for (int j = 0; j < Iterations; j++)
                {
                    var trainer = new SgdTrainer(Network) { LearningRate = Epsilon, L2Decay = Decay, Momentum = 0.9, BatchSize = TrainingSet.Count };
                    trainer.Train(input, new Volume(GetTrainingValues(_increment), new Shape(TrainingSet.Count)));
                }
            }
            _increment++;
        }



        Console.WriteLine("Done.");
    }
```

and test the result for example the letter a, I got values that are very illogical.

The probabilty of the last item/class of the network is ALWAYS the highest one.
For the training part I just use the method

```
    public double[] GetTrainingValues(int index)
    {
        double[] values = new double[TrainingSet.Count];
        values[index] = 1.0;
        return values;
    }
```

to define which class-position has to be the highest for image X with corresponding label Y.

Also if I use the same image for every label I get the same result!
Why?

Do You know how to train best, or can You recommend me a better library?

Thank you very much !

Comment: You should look into the MNIST example to get an idea of how the data is preprocessed and used as input for the network. all the info you are looking for should be in there

Comment: I am afraid that sadly, the documentation is extremely limited even in the examples and there is often simply no description at all.

Answer (score 0):

You should instantiate the trainer only once, outside the training loop.

```cs
var trainer = new SgdTrainer(Network) { 
                            LearningRate = Epsilon, 
                            L2Decay = Decay, 
                            Momentum = 0.9, 
                            BatchSize = TrainingSet.Count };

for (int j = 0; j < Iterations; j++)
{
    trainer.Train(input, 
                  new Volume(GetTrainingValues(_increment), 
                  new Shape(TrainingSet.Count)));
}
```